Getting a peculiar limit of sequence
I would like Mathematica to evaluate for me the limit:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} r_n$,
where $r_n = \min \{n-(1+\sqrt3) \left [\frac {n}{1+\sqrt3}\right] , (1+\sqrt3) \left [1+\frac {n}{1+\sqrt3}\right ]-n\}$.
So I write down the syntax :
a=1+Sqrt[3];

r[n_]=Min[n - a*Floor[n/a], a*Floor[1+n/a] - n]

Limit[r[n], n->Infinity]

and the result I am getting is :

The result should be Intermediate  but I do not know why I get this result. Any advise is apppreciated .

You apparently intend that n is a positive integer; use DiscreteLimit[r[n], n -> Infinity] which evaluates to Indeterminate

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

a = 1 + Sqrt[3];

r[n_] := Min[n - a*Floor[n/a], a*Floor[1 + n/a] - n]

DiscreteLimit[r[n], n -> Infinity]

(* Indeterminate *)

From documentation, "DiscreteLimit returns Indeterminate when it can prove that the limit does not exist, and returns unevaluated when no limit can be found."
#[r[n], n -> Infinity] & /@ {Limit, MinLimit, MaxLimit}

(* {Interval[{0, 1 + Sqrt[3]}], 0, 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])} *)

From documentation, "Limit returns unevaluated or an Interval when no limit can be found. If an Interval is returned, there are no guarantees that this is the smallest possible interval."

dmtri,
invest time to check the syntax:
'ClearAll' takes arguments, the 'All' does not refer to all variables, but to all properties of the variables in its argument.
Assignment '=' is different from ':=' but in this case, both work ok.
Try to see what's going on with a small sample, and look at the numerical values N@r[n] in a ListPlot with Option 'Joined->True'.
The pretty plot you got is the set of values for r[n] for successive values of n. There is no reason to expect convergence to an intermediate value for large n.
And don't get frustrated, we all went through the learning curve. Use F1, it really works wonders, and is very didactic.
